# Should the 'sapling-addon' tag be renamed?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just noticed the [sapling-addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sapling-addon) tag.

1. This tag seems to be the odd one out compared to other add-on tags in that it has 'addon' in the tag name whereas thers don't ([fspy](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fspy), [animation-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation-nodes), [sverchok](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sverchok)).
2. The official name of the add-on seems to be '[Sapling Tree Gen](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/add_curve/sapling.html#sapling-tree-gen)'.

I propose we rename the tag to [sapling-tree-gen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sapling-tree-gen).

Comment: For consistency sake I agree, `sapling-tree-gen` seems like a better name. I actually wouldn't mind seeing all addon related tags have the "addon" word in them for search and aggregation purposes, though I do see how it would get unwieldy and cumbersome

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yeah, I don't mind either way as long as it's consistent.

Comment: For now I think you can go ahead and rename it to [sapling-tree-gen], the other one seems more disruptive and would probably take a lot of work to retag

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I thought moderators had the ability to rename tags (I don't) without having to re-tag? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the link. Wasn't aware of that, learned something new. You'd make a fine moderator ;)

Comment: Either way if we are going to rename things I'd go with a better name structure and rename all addon tags with "addon" prefix, and all render engine tags with "render-engine" prefix. We need some consensus here, what are your thoughts?